# Not enough disk space on / and /boot for upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

Tags: partitioning, upgrade

I am having trouble upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS, getting a "Not enough free disk space" error. This is because I do not have enough free disk space on / (need 3618 M) and /boot (need 8397 k). I have emptied my trash and removed all of the old linux kernels. More generally, I am concerned about how full / is.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2        19G   16G  2.0G  89% /
udev            7.8G   12K  7.8G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.6G  940K  1.6G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.9G  184K  7.9G   1% /run/shm
/dev/md127p1    917G  169G  702G  20% /mnt/data0
/dev/sda1        89M   33M   51M  40% /boot
/dev/sda5       892G  289G  558G  35% /home

$ uname -r
3.2.0-67-generic

$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image 3.2.0.67.79 Generic Linux kernel image.
ii  linux-image-3.2.0-67-generic 3.2.0-67.101 Linux kernel image for version 3.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic 3.2.0.67.79 Generic Linux kernel image

$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid -o value -s UUID' to print the universally unique identifier
# for a device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name
# devices that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation 
# /home was on /dev/sda5 during installation
# /mnt/data0 was on /dev/md0 during installation
# swap was on /dev/sda3 during installation
```

Any suggestions on how to handle this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why not buy a larger hard-drive or external one for files ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is solvable. You might be able to free some space in / by removing the cached installation files and old headers:

```
sudo apt-get clean
dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
```

That's probably not going to be enough, in which case you could try uninstalling something big and non-default (for example a game). ...but there isn't much to be done with /boot.

I'd suggest holding of the upgrade, backing up files and repartitioning. What you have here is a classic case of over-partitioning, i.e. a redundant /boot and probably /home too. Many users seem to like the idea of breaking up HDDs into multiple partitions, without realizing the limitations. You would not have had this problem, if /boot and /home where inside one big / partition.